# Solving for $x$ using $\ln$ or any possible way.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots

$$
12.46x=1-(1+x)^{-20}
$$
I tried solving for $x$ using $\ln$ and other methods but the only answer i got was 0.8.
The correct answer is approximately to $0.05$.

Comment: There is no "exact" formula for the root you  are looking for. A numerical method will have to be used.

Comment: Have you tried the newton-method ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method If x is the interest rate, than $x_0$ (initial value) should be between 0% and 10%.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be rearranged to give
$$(1-12.46 x) (x+1)^{20}-1=0.$$

Expanding the $20^\text{th}$ power yields
$$-12.46 x^{21}-248.2 x^{20}-2347.4 x^{19}-14014.4 x^{18}-59228.7 x^{17}-188335.
   x^{16}-467446. x^{15}-927139. x^{14}-1.49207\times 10^6 x^{13}-1.96681\times 10^6
   x^{12}-2.1341\times 10^6 x^{11}-1.90803\times 10^6 x^{10}-1.40163\times 10^6
   x^9-839929. x^8-405430. x^7-154420. x^6-44864.7 x^5-9359.4 x^4-1227.4 x^3-59.2
   x^2+7.54 x=0$$

which by [Descartes rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) has exactly one positive root.

Solving for it yields $x=0.0500209$.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way
to get 
DumpsterDoofus's
result:

Let
$f(x)
=(1+ax)(1+x)^n-1
$
where
$a > 0$
and
$n > 0$.

$f(0) = -1$
and
$f(1)
=(1+a)2^n-1
> 0
$
since both
$1+a$ and $2^n$
are greater than $1$,
so
$f$ has a root between $0$ and $1$.

$f'(x)
=a(1+x)^n+(1+ax) n(1+x)^{n-1}
>0
$
since both terms are positive.

Therefore
$f$ has exactly one root
between $0$ and $1$.